# Replacing everything from a token except Alphabetic charaticers and periods

Tags: java, regex, string, tokenize

I'm using a string tokenizer that takes in one word at a time. When i'm reading in this token I want to strip everything from it that is no a Alphabetic character (A-Z) and a period(.). I'm currently working with something like this but it is leaving in a few strange characters along with things like ",". I was wondering if there is a more condescended and efficient way to something like this.

```
StringTokenizer biDoc = new StringTokenizer(new String(value.getBytes()));
while(biDoc.hasMoreElements()){
        String token = new String(biDoc.nextToken().replaceAll("[-@#$%^&*',;!?:()\'\"/<>]+_", "").replace("/[0-9]", ""));
        contentPrev.add(token);
    }
```

So i'm hoping that:
H''''i i""m Bob. I go--to--School and I_Like to Code.
Would display:
Hi im Bob. I gotoschool and ilike to code

This is my first question on here sorry if its formatted poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to strip everything from it that is no a Alphabetic character (A-Z) and a period(.)

To use with `replaceAll()`, this regex matches all those unwanted chars to be removed:

```
[^a-zA-Z.]+
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/qB6eR0/1)

Comment: Thanks this worked out for me! Sorry I can't upvote :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String token = new String(biDoc.nextToken().replaceAll("[-@#$%^&*',;!?:()\'\"/<>]+_", "").replace("/[0-9]", ""));
```

with

```
String token = new String(biDoc.nextToken().replaceAll("[\\W_]", "").replace("/[0-9]", ""));
```

In essence you don't want to know all the non alpha numeric characters and all those non alphanumeric characters can be represented with `\W`. And also to generate the output like this you would want to append a whitespace at the end of each loop like below.

```
contentPrev.add(token + " "); // Of course you should use StringBuilder or StringBuffer depending on the requirements of thread safety.
```

See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more information.

Comment: Why the star in `\W*` ?

Comment: Just to match all non-word characters

Comment: As a quantifier `0 or more` ?

Comment: Yes, You're right. Not really necessary. `+` is enough. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Well, anyway, (im off to bed), anything (with few exceptions) you put inside `[]` is parsed as a literal, so it's interpreted as plain star wich is already included in `\W`... You may want to move it out... Quantifiers are always placed outside of a charachter class `[]` !!